# Record Video from react-native-image-crop-picker not working in android 13 - Tab (Samsung Galaxy Tab A8)

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-image-crop-picker

*I am using react-native-image-crop-picker in my react-native application and recording video from the camera in Android It is returning [Error: User cancelled image selection]*

**NOTE:**
*It is working fine on Android 13 & 14 mobiles. But it is giving an error in Tab - Samsung Galaxy Tab A8 (Android 13).*

[react-native-image-crop-picker](https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker)

**Versions used**

> react-native-image-crop-picker v^0.40.2
>
> react-native v0.72.0
>
> react v18.2.0
>
> Android v13

**Platform** - Android

**Expected behaviour**

When we record video using ImagePicker.openCamera recorder video path must be returned as it returns when the image is captured.

**Actual behaviour**

After the video is recorded and we click ok it gives [Error: User cancelled image selection]

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Open Camera.
2. Record the Video and click OK.
3. Then we must get the recorded video path but it returns an error [Error: User cancelled image selection].

**AndroidManifest.xml.**

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
> ```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/>
```

**Sample code**

```
recordVideo = async() => {
  try {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,
      {
        title: "App Camera Permission",
        message:"App needs access to your camera ",
        buttonNeutral: "Ask Me Later",
        buttonNegative: "Cancel",
        buttonPositive: "OK"
      }
    );
    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
      ImagePicker.openCamera({
        mediaType:'video'
      })
        .then((image) => {
          console.log(" Image ", image)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          if (error && error.code === 'E_PICKER_CANCELLED') {
            return false;
          }
        })
    } else {
      console.log("Camera permission denied");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: It is working fine on Android 13 & 14 mobiles. But it is giving an error in Tab - Samsung Galaxy Tab A8 (Android 13).

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall using npm uninstall react-native-image-crop-picker and again install using npm i react-native-image-crop-picker and don't forget to add to android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/>
```

Comment: It is working fine on Android 13 & 14 mobiles. But it is giving an error in Tab - Samsung Galaxy Tab A8 (Android 13).

Answer (score 0):

## Please follow the final step of installation instructions for Android:

If you use SDK version >= 33, add following to app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/>
```

[Optional] If you want to use camera picker in your project, add following to app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

[Optional] If you want to use front camera, also add following to app/src/main/ AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />
```

Comment: It is working fine on Android 13 & 14 mobiles. But it is giving an error in Tab - Samsung Galaxy Tab A8 (Android 13).